# Sort URLs by considering parameters

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following list of URLs:

```
https://example.com/a?one=1&two=2
https://example.com/a?two=2&one=1
https://example.com/b?two=2&one=1
https://example.com/b?one=1&two=2
https://example.com/b?one=1
https://example.net/a/x?two=2&one=1
https://example.net/a/x?two=2&one=1
```

The result which I would like to get:

```
https://example.com/a?one=1&two=2
https://example.com/b?one=1&two=2
https://example.com/b?one=1
https://example.net/a/x?two=2&one=1
```

The problem is that the following links are "identical"; the only difference is the order of the parameters:

```
https://example.com/a?one=1&two=2
https://example.com/a?two=2&one=1
https://example.com/b?two=2&one=1
https://example.com/b?one=1&two=2
```

Is it possible to sort the URLs by considering the parameters? Not sure which approach should be used here, maybe someone already has a solution; I can only assume that it is achievable by using awk.

Comment: Not clear. You give the result you want, but don't explain what it means. What is the order key and direction ? How do you select 4 lines out of 7 ?

Comment: Sure, it's possible to process this list as you have described, but it would probably be easier to do in something a bit more capable than awk (Python would be my choice, but there are lots of options).

Comment: Your `example.com/b` links aren't identical, they assign different values to the parameters. Typo?

Comment: @tjm3772 Yeah, typo; fixed.

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: I suggest: [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)

Comment: `<url-list perl -F'\?\K|&' -laE 'say shift@F, join"&",sort@F' | sort -u`

Answer (score 1):

Solution in [TXR Lisp](https://nongnu.org/txr).

I added these two lines into the example data, to show they get sorted into the order based on their URL parameters first being sorted by key. They appear in the naive lexicographic order:

```
https://example.net/z?a=tiger&b=zebra
https://example.net/z?b=bear&a=aarvark
```

But the parameter `a` is to be considered more significant than `b`, so `a=aardvark` must sort before `a=tiger`. This is observed:

```
$ txr sort.tl  < urls 
https://example.com/a?one=1&two=2
https://example.com/b?one=1
https://example.com/b?two=2&one=1
https://example.net/a/x?two=2&one=1
https://example.net/z?b=bear&a=aarvark
https://example.net/z?a=tiger&b=zebra
```

The approach in the code is to parse the URLs into pieces and make objects out of them. In TXR Lisp, there is a concept called ["equality substitution"](https://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-02CDB347) whereby we program a structure object to use an alternative key to represent it under the `equal` function. We do this by writing a one-argument method called `equal`. The method takes the object itself (the "self") and is called in order to deliver the equality substitute. In our case, we have it like:

```
   (:method equal (me) me.key)
```

This says "to compare me for equality with something else, don't actually compare me, but rather use my `key` slot instead of me.

We populate this `key` slot of the `url` structure with a normalized
representation: a vector consisting of the domain, path, and sorted association list of URL parameters.

With the equality substitution, we can just `uniq` the URL objects, `sort` them and then print them out as strings again.

```
(defstruct url ()
  urlstr
  prot
  domain
  path
  paramstr
  params

  ;; slot computed in :postinit
  key

  (:postinit (me)
    (set me.params [nsort me.params : car]
         me.key (vec me.domain me.path me.params)))

  (:method equal (me) me.key)

  (:method print (me stream : pretty-p)
    (if pretty-p (put-string me.urlstr stream) :)))

(defun parse-url (str)
  (match `@prot://@domain/@path?@paramstr` str
    (let ((params (collect-each ((param (spl "&" paramstr)))
                    (match `@var=@val` param
                      (cons var val)))))
      (new url
           urlstr str
           prot prot
           domain domain
           path path
           paramstr paramstr
           params params))))

(flow (get-lines)
  (mapcar parse-url)
  uniq
  sort
  tprint)
```

Answer (score 1):

A Perl one-liner:

```
<url-list perl -lpE 's|\?\K.*|join"&",sort split/&/,$&|e' | sort -u
```

After urls (stored in file `url-list`) have been normalised by Perl, `sort -u` sorts the list and discards duplicates.

- `-l` - chomp the line-ending
- `-p` - print each line of input after manipulation
- `-E` - program follows - is run on each line of input
- `s|RE|CMD|e` - replace whatever `RE` matches with result of executing `CMD`
- `\?\K.*` - regex for "everything after a literal `?`". match stored in `$&`
- `split RE, STRING` - split string (`$&`) on regex (literal `&`)
- `sort LIST` - sort the pieces
- `join SEPARATOR, LIST` - join them up again with `&` as separator

Could be done with `gawk` but probably a bit longer.

POSIX `awk` doesn't support sorting very well.

Comment: This method outputs the normalised urls and not the original versions, since the question considers them to be equivalent. However, note that it is application-dependent if they actually are equivalent. cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_normalization